# Spring Framework: Why command line argument "--argument-name=" throws Invalid argument syntax?

Tags: spring

For `Spring Boot` having the intention to execute the following command:

- `java -jar ./target/command-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --user-name=` (two `-` and `=` )

Throws

```
[main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: ---user-name=
    at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.parse(SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.<init>(SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments$Source.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:42)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.manuel.jordan.Command01Application.main(Command01Application.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

But If use:

- `java -jar ./target/command-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -user-name=` (one `-` and `=`)
- `java -jar ./target/command-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --user-name` (two `-` and *not* `=` )

Pass

The app developed has internal validation if the argument `--user-name` use `=` and there is no value. It is not critical of course because:

- The value would be assumed how empty and a default internal value should be assumed.
- Either `--user-name` or `-user-name=` arguments can be used instead too.

Why `Spring Boot` has this control validation?. What is the reason about this?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why Spring Boot has this control validation?. What is the reason about this? working with `--name-argument=`

Comment: An argument passed on the command line is required to have a value, specified by `=`. So whent `=` is available as Spring expects a value (it is a Spring class not Spring Boot). When using the other syntax a single `-` is ignored as it isn't a property. This is also explained in the [source of the class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/env/SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java#L30)

Comment: Has sense your reply, I read the javadoc, proceed to put it how an answer, to check it how resolved.